# How to auto re-run sbt project in scala

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, auto-compile

I have created an **sbt project** to learn simple crud operation using **akka-http**. First I added simple routes to check if it is working or not.

By running `sbt run` command, I found that it runs locally without any error.

But when I make some changes to the project (for example: Adding `println` statement to the running code) it does not auto compiling.
Every time I have to exit (`ctrl+c`) the running sbt. And again run to see the updated code.

So my question is that how to auto compile sbt project while running the project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not handled by default by sbt, but there's a plugin for that: [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver). It will trigger the restart of your application as soon as there are any changes in the source code of your application.

Just add

```
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.1")
```

in your `build.sbt` and then start the app with:

```
sbt ~reStart
```

Comment: I found that sbt-revolver was already there in plugin.sbt file. It is now auto compiling using ~reStart. Thanks

Comment: You can approve and/or upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: If you are using play framework, in that case you don't need sbt-revolver.
sbt launches Play with the auto-reload feature enabled. When you make a request, Play will automatically recompile and restart your server if any files have changed.
If needed the application will restart automatically.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlayConsole#Development-mode